# Clang-Tidy changes signature of c file, but not the associated header

Tags: clang, constants, signature, clang-tidy

I have this c file

```
#include "pointer.h"
int switcher(int * i) {
 int a = *i;
    switch (a) {
        case 1: 
            return 0;
        default: 
            return 1;
    }
}
```

and the associated header contains only one line

```
int switcher(int * i);
```

This compiles using clang.

If I now use clang-tidy (clang-tidy -fix pointer.c  -checks=* -header-filter=.* ) I get the following result

```
#include "pointer.h"
int switcher(const int * i) {
    int a = *i;
    switch (a) {
        case 1: 
            return 0;
        default: 
            return 1;
    }
}
```

and the header

```
#ifndef _HOME_GWE_PROJEKTE_CLANG_TIDY_POINTER_H
#define _HOME_GWE_PROJEKTE_CLANG_TIDY_POINTER_H

int switcher(int * i);

#endif
```

The signature of the function has been changed form (int *i) to (const int*i) which is nice. The header file has also been altered (guards), but the signature stays the very same. Thus. the code does not compile any more.

My compile_commands.json looks like this

```
[
{
  "directory": "/home/gwe/projekte/clang/tidy",
  "command": "clang -c pointer.c -I.",
  "file": "pointer.c"
}
]
```

Is this a clang-tidy bug or am I doing it wrong?
Thanks for your help?

Best regards, Georg

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=33219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is reported to llvm.org.

bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=33219